# Dose convergence in integral and measure imply convergence in L

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Suppose a sequence of function $f_n \mapsto f$ converges in measure and in integral. by integral I mean $\int f_n \,d\mu \mapsto \int f \,d\mu$. Does that mean they converge in L1. It seems not entire true to me e.g. consider $f$ with compact support whose positive value cancels with the negatives and moves right $+ 1$ for each $n.$ Any hints?

Comment: I took the liberty of changing $du$ to $d\mu$ in this question. That you're not very must accustomed to standard usages in TeX and LaTeX and MathJax is conspicuous from the fact that you did not set the isolated $f$ or the isolated $n$ or the $+1$ in math mode, so I suspected you didn't know how to write $\mu.$ Although the change from $u$ to $\mu$ is something about which some may disagree, one thing you did was plainly incorrect: the lack of space between $f$ and $d\mu,$ so I added that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases} n &\text{ if }x\in \big[0,\frac{1}{n}\big],\\ -n &\text{ if }x\in \big[-\frac{1}{n},0\big]\end{cases}$$ Then $f_n\xrightarrow{\text{ almost everywhere }\implies \text{ in measure}} 0$. Also, $0=\int_\Bbb R f_n\longrightarrow \int_\Bbb R0=0$, but $\int_\Bbb R|f_n-0|=2$.

Comment: That convergence arrow tho, lol! +1, good counterexample

Comment: Is it looks nice?